# Converting a String to a SHA256 Hash Without CommonCrypto

Tags: swift, cryptography

I'm trying to work with string encryption in my app. I need to convert a string (`let string = "hello"`) to a SHA256 string.

I am not able to import CommonCrypto, and can't build a bridging header because I need to stay fully Swift. (No Cocoapods either)

### **tl;dr**

Is there a way to convert a string to a SHA256 hash with native Swift frameworks, or just manually do the entire conversion in a function?

Comment: What is the problem with importing CommonCrypto? Is it for a non-Apple platform?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, it is.

Comment: This isn't built in. You'll just need to write the algorithm in Swift. See CryptoSwift for an example. https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: @RobNapier I used snippets of source code from CryptoSwift, if you want to make an answer basically saying what you said I'll solve it.

Comment: It's fine (and good) to answer your own question and accept it if it's a generally useful answer.